# Semi-automatic classification plugin - Conversion Problem

Tags: qgis-plugins, sentinel-2, scp

I'm trying to Preprocess Sentinel-2 Images to use for the classification in the SCP Plugin but I'm hitting a wall at the final step before inputting the Data as Training Input for the Plugin.
I did everything step after step as in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ceyhm3DlZNY&t=726s

Though when I come to the step (10:17 Preprocess the Data) I get them with RT_clip... in my QGIS but they are simply white or if I copy the style from the clip raster data they turn black.

Here is how it looks when I have one of the clipped visible.
[image]
And as an example here with the RT activated with OSM beneath it for reference.
[image]

When I look at the TIFF files in my folder they are not only white at all, so I suspect it is some wrong settings in my QGIS. Does somebody have an idea how this is fixable?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the Raster Properties Dialog of each RT_clip-Layer in QGIS
Select Style
Go to Band Rendering
Set the min value to 1

It is best to set the value for "Use value as NoData" to 1 in the Preprocessing Dialog (Sentinel-2 conversion).

There is no hint in the video or in the tutorial, but you can find it in the help of the tool.